# Issues with readLine

Tags: java, file

Just try to get the line right in the while statement

```
try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("Original.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String strFullName;
    while ((strFullName = br.readLine()) != null) {
        int intSpaceLocation = strFullName.indexOf(" ");
        String strLastName = strFullName.substring(0, intSpaceLocation);
        String strFirstName = strFullName.substring(intSpaceLocation + 1);
        System.out.println("First Name = " + strFirstName + " Last Name = " + strLastName);
    }
    br.close();
    fr.close();
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

**I am trying to get each line from a file and trying to split it with a space, but it only does it for the first line**

Output:
First Name = Todd Last Name = Jackson

Comment: `ready()` is not the usual method, read here https://www.baeldung.com/java-buffered-reader#2-reading-line-by-line

Comment: And hint: learn about try-with-resources in java. Your code is full of subtle errors. Also: NEVER go with an empty catch block. That is just HIDING errors. You dont want that. And out of curiosity, where did you pick up to write that file reading like this? (seriously, I have seen the same bad style like 5 times this week, and wondering where that is coming from)

Comment: There is a nice way to read line by line, read here https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/read-file-line-by-line/ . You can also use Java 11 features.

Comment: Thanks so much, everyone. I am a beginner, so I will keep all of this in mind.